# How to create a timer in Spritekit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, nstimer

Ive figured out how to make a timer in a single-view application, but not Spritekit. When I use the following code, I get 2 errors(listed below). Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks, Jack.

The timer.

```
if(!_scorelabel) {
    _scorelabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Courier-Bold"];

    _scorelabel.fontSize = 200;
    _scorelabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    _scorelabel.fontColor = [SKColor colorWithHue: 0 saturation: 0 brightness: 1 alpha: .5];
    [self addChild:_scorelabel];
}
_scorelabel = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1 target:self selector:@selector(Timercount)userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

The errors

```
Incompatible pointer types assigned to 'SKLabelNode*' from 'NSTimer*'
Undeclared selector 'Timercount'
```

Comment: don't use NSTimer! See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23978854/201863

Answer (score 4):

In Swift usable:

In Sprite Kit do not use `NSTimer, GCD or performSelector:afterDelay:` because these timing methods ignore a node's, scene's or the view's paused state. Moreover you do not know at which point in the game loop they are executed which can cause a variety of issues depending on what your code actually does.

```
var actionwait = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
        var timesecond = Int()
        var actionrun = SKAction.runBlock({
                timescore++
                timesecond++
                if timesecond == 60 {timesecond = 0}
                scoreLabel.text = "Score Time: \(timescore/60):\(timesecond)"
            })

        scoreLabel.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([actionwait,actionrun])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the `NSTimer` you created to an `SKLabelNode`.  To fix your first error, change the last line to:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(Timercount) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

You are getting the second error because you are setting the timer to call a method called `Timercount`, but you don't have one.

Comment: Also an alternative to the NSTimer is to use SKActions.         SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.0f];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction performSelector:@selector(method:) onTarget:self], wait]];
SKAction *repeat   = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];
[self runAction:repeat]; 


- (void)method {
...
}

Comment: not just an alternative but THE way to do it. NSTimer won't stop firing if the game/scene/node is paused for instance.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I am assuming that the OP has everything set up already to manage/stop the timer.