# SpriteKit - Creating a timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, sprite-kit

How can I create a timer that fires every two seconds that will increment the score by one on a HUD I have on my screen? This is the code I have for the HUD:

```
    @implementation MyScene
{
    int counter;
    BOOL updateLabel;
    SKLabelNode *counterLabel;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        counter = 0;

        updateLabel = false;

        counterLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
        counterLabel.name = @"myCounterLabel";
        counterLabel.text = @"0";
        counterLabel.fontSize = 20;
        counterLabel.fontColor = [SKColor yellowColor];
        counterLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeCenter;
        counterLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeBottom;
        counterLabel.position = CGPointMake(50,50); // change x,y to location you want
        counterLabel.zPosition = 900;
        [self addChild: counterLabel];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not overriding the update(currentTime) method ? "it is called exactly once per frame, so long as the scene is presented in a view and is not paused"

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In Sprite Kit **do not use** `NSTimer`, `performSelector:afterDelay:` or Grand Central Dispatch (GCD, ie any `dispatch_...` method) because these timing methods ignore a node's, scene's or the view's `paused` state. Moreover you do not know at which point in the game loop they are executed which can cause a variety of issues depending on what your code actually does.

The only two sanctioned ways to perform something time-based in Sprite Kit is to either use the SKScene `update:` method and using the passed-in currentTime parameter to keep track of time.

Or more commonly you would just use an action sequence that starts with a wait action:

```
id wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:2.5];
id run = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    // your code here ...
}];
[node runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[wait, run]]];
```

And to run the code repeatedly:

```
[node runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[wait, run]]]];
```

Alternatively you can also use `performSelector:onTarget:` instead of `runBlock:` or perhaps use a `customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:` if you need to mimick the SKScene `update:` method and don't know how to forward it to the node or where forwarding would be inconvenient.

See [SKAction reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013017) for details.

---

**UPDATE:** Code examples using Swift

Swift 5

```
 run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([
     SKAction.run( /*code block or a func name to call*/ ),
     SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.5)
     ])))
```

Swift 3

```
let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration:2.5)
let action = SKAction.run {
    // your code here ...
}
run(SKAction.sequence([wait,action]))
```

Swift 2

```
let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.5)
let run = SKAction.runBlock {
    // your code here ...
}
runAction(SKAction.sequence([wait, run]))
```

And to run the code repeatedly:

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([wait, run])))
```

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Works perfectly! Just to prevent error from other users, I suggest adding a closed bracket on the third line to stop syntax errors.

Comment: fixed typo, added repeat example

Comment: How would I translate this into Swift?

Comment: I added Swift code fragments. Haven't tested whether it compiles. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Repeating the action did not help because it takes a big performance toll. I need to run the action every second, maybe its too intense. I recommend using the update method for that reason. Edit: I take it back, for some reason Product>Clean resolved the problem.

Comment: What if you need to calculate something that takes x amount of time where x is more than a few frames? I don't think it's fair to say never use dispatch_async. We don't our game to hang while we wait for some loop to finish.

Comment: High CPU usage occurs with SKAction.repeatForever in xCode 11.3.1, CPU Usage never reduces less than 50% and most around 77% of usage, Is there is some alternative way? As soon as i have stopped the animation, CPU usage reducing to 0-1%. I have tested on real device and due to high CPU usage, fps drops happening.

Answer (score 5):

In Swift usable:

```
var timescore = Int()  
var actionwait = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
            var timesecond = Int()
            var actionrun = SKAction.runBlock({
                    timescore++
                    timesecond++
                    if timesecond == 60 {timesecond = 0}
                    scoreLabel.text = "Score Time: \(timescore/60):\(timesecond)"
                })
            scoreLabel.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([actionwait,actionrun])))
```

Answer (score 5):

I've taken the swift example above and added in leading zeros for the clock.

```
    func updateClock() {
    var leadingZero = ""
    var leadingZeroMin = ""
    var timeMin = Int()
    var actionwait = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)
    var timesecond = Int()
    var actionrun = SKAction.runBlock({
        timeMin++
        timesecond++
        if timesecond == 60 {timesecond = 0}
        if timeMin  / 60 <= 9 { leadingZeroMin = "0" } else { leadingZeroMin = "" }
        if timesecond <= 9 { leadingZero = "0" } else { leadingZero = "" }

        self.flyTimeText.text = "Flight Time [ \(leadingZeroMin)\(timeMin/60) : \(leadingZero)\(timesecond) ]"
    })
    self.flyTimeText.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([actionwait,actionrun])))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the full code to build a timer for SpriteKit with Xcode 9.3 and Swift 4.1

[image]

> In our example the score label will be incrementd by 1 every 2 seconds.
>   Here's final result

Good, let's start!

### 1) The score label

First of all we need a label

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    private let label = SKLabelNode(text: "Score: 0")
}
```

### 2) The score label goes into the scene

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    private let label = SKLabelNode(text: "Score: 0")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.label.fontSize = 60
        self.addChild(label)
    }
}
```

Now the label is at the center of the screen. Let's run the project to see it.

[image]

> Please note that at this point the label is not being updated!

### 3) A counter

We also want to build a counter property which will hold the current value displayed by the label. We also want the label to be updated as soon as the counter property is changed so...

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    private let label = SKLabelNode(text: "Score: 0")
    private var counter = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.label.text = "Score: \(self.counter)"
        }
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.label.fontSize = 60
        self.addChild(label)

        // let's test it!
        self.counter = 123
    }
}
```

[image]

### 4) The actions

Finally we want to build an action that every 2 seconds will increment counter

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    private let label = SKLabelNode(text: "Score: 0")
    private var counter = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.label.text = "Score: \(self.counter)"
        }
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.label.fontSize = 60
        self.addChild(label)
        // 1 wait action
        let wait2Seconds = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)
        // 2 increment action
        let incrementCounter = SKAction.run { [weak self] in
            self?.counter += 1
        }
        // 3. wait + increment
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait2Seconds, incrementCounter])
        // 4. (wait + increment) forever
        let repeatForever = SKAction.repeatForever(sequence)

        // run it!
        self.run(repeatForever)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The following code creates a new thread and waits 2 seconds before doing something on the main thread:

```
BOOL continueIncrementingScore = YES;

dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("timer", NULL);, ^{
    while(continueIncrementingScore) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // this is performed on the main thread - increment score here

        });
    }
});
```

Whenever you want to stop it - just set `continueIncrementingScore` to `NO`

Comment: bad example because there's dispatch_after