# Need help incorporating "Preform Selector: WithObject: AfterDelay:" with the SKScene being paused

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene

I need help incorporating the

```
PreformSelector: WithObject: AfterDelay:
```

With the SKScene being paused.
I am making a game where there is a pause button which pauses the scene. This, however does not affect the

```
PreformSelector: WithObject: AfterDelay:
```

function which calls the "Reload" function. Without this fixed the user can fire a shot, press pause, wait for the reload function to be called, un-pause, and shoot. This makes it so the user can continuously fire without having to reload in "game time". Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spritekit - Creating a timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978209/spritekit-creating-a-timer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, because keeping track of timing and storing the selectors and objects etc. with that method would be very cumbersome.

Instead, make use of SpriteKit's `+[SKAction waitForDuration:]` action.

You would want to do something like the following (I'm assuming this code takes place somewhere in one of your scene's methods):

```
// Replace 2.0 below with however long you want to wait, in seconds
SKAction *waitAction = [SKAction waitForDuration:2.0];

// I'm assuming your "Reload" method is a method declared in your scene's
// class and not some other class, so I'm using "self" as the target here.
SKAction *reloadAction = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(Reload) onTarget:self];

SKAction *sequenceAction = [SKAction sequence:@[waitAction, reloadAction]];

// Since I'm assuming this is in your scene implementation, `self` here
// refers to your scene node.
[self runAction:sequenceAction];
```

Since actions can be paused and resumed, when you pause your scene with `self.paused = YES;` your actions will also get paused and will resume where they left off when you later unpause your scene.