# Invalidate all active NSTimers in SKScene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

What would be the most straightforward method to invalidate every active NSTimer in an SKScene, if multiple NSTimers are firing from multiple different functions inside the SKScene?

For example, every SKAction in an SKScene can be cancelled with the removeAllActions function. Could the NSTimer invalidation be implemented similarly?

An example of a timer setup that my SKScene has, written in swift:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(kWalkSpeed, target: self, selector: Selector("animatePlayerNode"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: it's best *not* to use nstimer in the first place: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23978854/201863

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general method would be to store all created timers in an array, and then loop over them to invalidate.