# Trigger spritekit animation

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit

Hey all I have a Spritekit animation that I want to trigger when the user wins the level. This is what I have

```
 if([[other name] isEqualToString:@"win"])
{
    NSLog(@"WE HAVE WON THE LEVEL");

    [bomb removeFromParent];

    [self saveUserInfo];

    [[self view] performSelector:@selector(presentScene:) withObject:[LevelSelectScene scene] afterDelay:2];
}
```

How should I approach triggering the animation right after the bomb is removed from the parent?

Comment: Don't use performSelector:afterDelay: in Sprite Kit. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23978854/201863 Then use Actions, you can then use the runAction's completionBlock or the runBlock action.

Comment: Sorry I am so new and still learning at this, how would my code look by switching it with the one in the example you have given?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)gameOver
{
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction runBlock:^{
        [bomb removeFromParent];
        [self yourAnimation];
        [self saveUserInfo];
    }] ,[SKAction waitForDuration:yourDelay], [SKAction runBlock:^{
        GameOverScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
        [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition:[SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionLeft duration:0.5]];
    }]]]];
}
```