# how to increase the value of an NSNumber every 5 seconds?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

i'm building a game for which i the gravity as:

```
self.physicsworld.gravity = CGVectorMake(gravityX , gravity-Y);
```

i want to change the forces acting on the sprite node with time.

since i'm a newbie, i'm not able to code a loop(s) so that the gravity changes over time thereby changing the difficulty of the game. if i want the float variable gravityX to increment by 0.5 every 5 seconds what should be the code implemented.

the main problem i'm facing with using the FOR LOOP here is in the CONDITION; I don't know how to make the computer understand actual time since the game started.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spritekit - Creating a timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978209/spritekit-creating-a-timer) - use the timing methods provided by Sprite Kit, **do not** use NSTimer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the `SKAction` class. Add the following method to your `SKScene` subclass, and call it when you want gravity to start increasing. I've included both the Objective-C and the Swift version.

Objective-C:

```
- (void)startGravityIncrease {
    SKAction *blockAction = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        CGVector gravity = self.physicsWorld.gravity;
        gravity.dx += 0.5;
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = gravity;
    }];
    SKAction *waitAction = [SKAction waitForDuration:5];
    SKAction *sequenceAction = [SKAction sequence:@[waitAction, blockAction]];
    SKAction *repeatAction = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequenceAction];

    [self runAction:repeatAction];
}
```

Swift:

```
func startGravityIncrease() {
    let blockAction = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in
        self.physicsWorld.gravity.dx += 0.5
    }
    let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(5)
    let sequenceAction = SKAction.sequence([waitAction, blockAction])
    let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequenceAction)

    self.runAction(repeatAction)
}
```