# SKSpriteNode won't appear... Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm using Sprite Kit Xcode 6 and I need to add a sprite and it won't appear when I try to add it... I created a Cocoa Touch Class and The files are below..

**level1Layout.m**

> ```
> #import "level1Layout.h"
> #import "GameScene.h"
>
> @implementation level1Layout 
>
> SKSpriteNode *testEnemy;
>
> -(void) addSprite{
>     NSLog(@"FFFFFFF");
>     [self addChild:testEnemy];
>
> }
>
> -(void) testMethod{
>     NSLog(@"adad");
>
>     testEnemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"TestEnemy"];
>     testEnemy.position = CGPointMake(512, 384);
>
>     NSLog(@"%f", testEnemy.position.x);
>     NSLog(@"%f", testEnemy.position.y);
>
>     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
>                                      target:self
>                                    selector:@selector(addSprite)
>                                    userInfo:nil
>                                     repeats:NO];
>
> }
>
> -(void) runAddLevel1Layout{
>     [[GameScene new] runLevel1Layout];
> }
>
> @end
> ```

(I used the NSLogs to make sure it was being called)

**level1Layout.h**

> ```
> #import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
> #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
> #import "GameScene.h"
>
> @interface level1Layout : SKScene
>
> -(void) testMethod;
> -(void) runAddLevel1Layout;
> -(void) addSprite;
>
> @end
> ```

And the main class where it starts, if someone wants me to put it in, just let me know.

**GameScene.m**

> ```
> #import "GameScene.h"
> #import "level1Layout.h"
>
> @implementation GameScene
>
> SKSpriteNode *trans;
> SKSpriteNode *level1ButtonRed;
>
> -(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
>     /* Setup your scene here */
>
>     level1ButtonRed = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"levelButtonRed"];
> }
>
> -(void) runLevel1Layout{
>     [[level1Layout new] testMethod];
> }
>
> +(void) addLevel1Layout{
>
> }
>
> -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
>     /* Called when a touch begins */
>
>     for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
>         CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
>         trans.position = location;
>
>         [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2
>                                          target:self
>                                        selector:@selector(runLevel1Layout)
>                                        userInfo:nil
>                                         repeats:NO];
>     }
> }
>
> -(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
>     /* Called before each frame is rendered */
> }
>
> @end
> ```

Anyone know?

Comment: you are not adding the sprite as child. Also you shouldn't be using nstimer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978209/spritekit-creating-a-timer/23978854#23978854

Comment: Can we see how `testMethod` is being called? i.e. the main class, as you call it. 
@LearnCocos2D is he not adding the sprite as a child in the `addSprite` method?

Comment: I tried using what you told me to do, but the methods were never called. @LearnCocos2D

Comment: I added 'GameScene.m' into the question, and 'testMethod' is called in there. The 'GameScene.h' file just declares the methods. @Andriko13

Comment: Thanks, what are your NSLog messages? I don't think addSprite is being called with your NSTimer there