# Sprite Kit, vibrating sprite

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have two scenes (MainScene and ResultScene). The game starts with the MainScene. The first presentation of MainScene is good, the game runs smoothly, but if the game changes to ResultScene and from ResultScene back to MainScene, my hero sprite is vibrating.

Here's the method from ResultScene:

```
func presentScene() {
    let scene = MainScene()
    scene.size = self.frame.size
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFit
    self.view!.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    self.view!.presentScene(scene)
}
```

Here's the way how i move the hero:

```
var velocity: CGFloat = 360
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    self.myHero?.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = self.velocity
}
```

And here's I modify the velocity:

```
self.increaseVelocityTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(17, target: self, selector: Selector("increaseVelocity"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func increaseVelocity() {
   self.velocity += 60
}
```

Comment: Not enough and the wrong code. Post the code where you change the hero's position or rotation and any variables involved therein.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D
Sorry for late answer. I move the hero in this way:

   var velocity: CGFloat = 360


override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) { 
self.myHero.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = self.velocity
}

Comment: and how is velocity modified? please edit your question with the code, don't add it in a comment

Comment: you should definitely not use nstimer but update or skaction to increase velocity, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978209/spritekit-creating-a-timer

Comment: The vibration is fully independent how i modify the velocity, because if i turn off the timer, the vibration is still there. Immediately begins when the MainScene is presenteted secondly.
@LearnCocos2D

Comment: Does your game also get slower? Like lag