# Spawning a Spritekit node at a random time

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nstimer, skspritenode

I'm making a game where I have a node that is spawning and falling from the top of the screen. However I want to make the nodes spawn at random time intervals between a period of 3 seconds. So one spawns in 1 second, the next in 2.4 seconds, the next in 1.7 seconds, and so forth forever. I am struggling with what the code should be for this.

Code I currently have for spawning node:

```
    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(3, withRange: 2)
    let spawn = SKAction.runBlock { addTears()
    }

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, spawn])
    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawn))
```

The code for my addTears() function is:

```
func addTears() {
        let Tears = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "Tear")
        Tears.position = CGPointMake(Drake1.position.x, Drake1.position.y - 2)
        Tears.zPosition = 3
        addChild(Tears)

    //gravity
    Tears.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (circleOfRadius: 150)
    Tears.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true

    //contact
    Tears.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (circleOfRadius: Tears.size.width/150)
    Tears.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = contactType.Tear.rawValue
    Tears.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = contactType.Bucket.rawValue
    }
```

Comment: Use `arc4random_uniform()` function to generate random numbers. And then assign them in the timeInterval.

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example of how to assign them in the timeInterval?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spawn nodes at random times combing waitForDuration:withRange and runBlock: in an SKAction sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851619/spawn-nodes-at-random-times-combing-waitfordurationwithrange-and-runblock-in-a)

Answer (score 4):

It's not advisable that you use `NSTimer` with SpriteKit (see [SpriteKit - Creating a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978209/spritekit-creating-a-timer)). Instead, to generate random times you could use [`SKAction.waitForDuration:withRange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/waitForDuration:withRange:)

> Creates an action that idles for a randomized period of time.
>
> When the action executes, the action waits for the specified amount of
>   time, then ends...
>
> **Each time the action is executed, the action computes a new random
>   value for the duration.** The duration may vary in either direction by
>   up to half of the value of the *durationRange* parameter...

To spawn nodes at random times you could combine `waitForDuration:withRange` with `runBlock:` together in an `SKAction` sequence. For example:

```
// I'll let you adjust the numbers correctly...
let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3, withRange: 2)
let spawn = SKAction.run {
    // Create a new node and it add to the scene...
}

let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, spawn])
self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence))
// self in this case would probably be your SKScene subclass.
```

Comment: I replaced my code with this code and for some reason my game wouldn't start. My node is already created so I added it to the area that says // Create new node and it add to the scene... . Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: When you say "wouldn't start"? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: The scene that runs this code is my second scene, the first is a "tap to start". When i run the game and try to tap to start, it doesn't load my second scene.

Comment: Is it freezing? Does anything on he second scene get run? Where have you put the code I supplied in my answer?

Comment: I put the code in my didMoveToView. I think it is just freezing because the second scene does not run.

Comment: @NickyNick321 try putting a log in the run block. Guessing you have your delay wrong and it is stuck in an infinite loop. Also I would recommend doing runAction:withKey so you can stop this action when you need to do something like game over.

Comment: You were right I added the log and there is an infinite loop. Would you know how I should go about fixing this?

Comment: If you update your question with your code, including my answer above, I can take a look for you.