# Spawn nodes at random times combing waitForDuration:withRange and runBlock: in an SKAction sequence

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I am making a game with SpriteKit where I have nodes spawning at the top of the screen and falling. However, I want these nodes to spawn at a random time interval between 0.1 and 3 seconds. For example, the first node spawns in 1.3 seconds, the next in 1.8, then 2.5, then 0.8, and so forth forever. I'm not sure how to utilize the waitForDuration function to do this. The code that I currently have is:

```
let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(3, withRange: 2)
let spawn = SKAction.runBlock { addTears()
}

let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, spawn])
self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawn))
```

This code freezes my game when I try to run it. I removed the addTears() and put a log, and there was an infinite loop on the log. I need to know how to get rid of this.

The code for my addTears() func is:

```
func addTears() {
    let Tears = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "Tear")
    Tears.position = CGPointMake(Drake1.position.x, Drake1.position.y - 2)
    Tears.zPosition = 3
    addChild(Tears)

//gravity
Tears.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (circleOfRadius: 150)
Tears.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true

//contact
Tears.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (circleOfRadius: Tears.size.width/150)
Tears.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = contactType.Tear.rawValue
Tears.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = contactType.Bucket.rawValue
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember well, the `waitForDuration:withRange:` method works like so :
if you put a *duration of 3 (seconds)* and a *range of 1 seconds* the random value that you get will be *between 2 and 4 seconds*. That said, you should use those value for what you described : `let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.55, withRange: 1.45)`

For the freeze problem, if you pasted your code correctly here the problem come with this line `self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawn))` where you should instead be calling your `sequence` like this : `self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence))`.

*PS : At a certain point you still might want to control the amount of tears on screen at the same time.*

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. If I wanted to randomize the speed at which each of these tears fell, as well, is there a method I can use for that? They are currently falling at a constant speed using this:    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -7)

Comment: You could probably change some setting on your tears' physicsBody (mass, ...). But, if what you're looking for is, for example, make some tears drop constantly I think you should give a look at SKEmitterNode / Particle Emitter where within a .sks file, or programmatically, you'll be able to set several variables with range. Try to play with it :)

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the responses. I would upvote but I need more reputation.

Comment: This was the best explanation ever, you were right :) so basically the calculation it does is duration -+ range. So, if duration is 10 and range 5, the random will go from 5 to 15.