# stop/start NSTimer when app goes to background

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, nstimer, skscene

as the title suggests, i am trying to stop my NSTimer when my game goes to background and start it back when the game starts again. the interruptions obviously could be such as receiving a phone call etc..

i am using the following code in app delegate to stop and restart the scene when the app gets interrupted, but it does not stop the timer.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
    view.scene.paused = YES;
}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
    view.scene.paused = NO;
}
```

in my scene where i place the timer, i have placed the observers in `-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size` method. here are the observers:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(goBackground)
         name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
         object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(backBackground)
         name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

and the selector methods:

```
- (void) goBackground {
    [timer invalidate], timer = nil;
}

- (void) backBackground {
    if([timer isValid]) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

and i am also trying to deallocating the observers as follows:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}
```

the code above gets fired, i have placed an NSLog on all the above methods. but what happens is, it works for scene 1 which is the place for level 1 and when the player wins level 1 and goes to level two and i recreate the app interruption scenario again, it comes back and works for a few seconds before the game crashes.

obviously my code is not working and i have tried every which way i know how to get around that, but to no avail. the timer i have is just to show how much time is left in the level and has nothing to do with the win/lose scenario.(this maybe a bit of extra info which may not be needed to know).

is there anyway that i can stop and restart my timer when my game goes to background? i truly appreciate any help.

i don't know if the timer code is needed but it is as follows:

```
- (void) gameTimerLabel {
    gameTimerLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"ArialRoundedMTBold"];
   // gameTimerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _lives];
    gameTimerLabel.fontSize = 20.0;
    gameTimerLabel.fontColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:135.0/255 green:207.0/255 blue:232.0/255 alpha:0.6];
    gameTimerLabel.position = gameTimerLabel.position = CGPointMake(270, 282);
    [self addChild:gameTimerLabel];
}

- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    if(secondsLeft > 0 ){
        secondsLeft -- ;
        //hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
        minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
        seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
        gameTimerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds];
    }
    else{
        secondsLeft = 70;
    }
}

-(void)countdownTimer{

    secondsLeft = hours = minutes = seconds = 0;
    if([timer isValid]) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

it is basically just a count down timer nothing fancy.

Edit:

Ben-G, was right. there is almost no way to manage NSTimer in background/foreground, so i used the SKAction approach and did get the job done. for those who are interested, here is the working code:

```
@implementation MyScene {
SKLabelNode *gameTimerLabel;
int countDownInt;
    int secondsLeft;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
secondsLeft = 70;
[self gameTimerLabel];
}
    return self;
}

- (void) gameTimerLabel {
    gameTimerLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"ArialRoundedMTBold"];
    gameTimerLabel.fontSize = 20.0;
    gameTimerLabel.fontColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:135.0/255 green:207.0/255 blue:232.0/255 alpha:0.6];
    gameTimerLabel.position = gameTimerLabel.position = CGPointMake(270, 282);
    [self addChild:gameTimerLabel];
    countDownInt = secondsLeft;
    SKAction *updateLabel = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        gameTimerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %02d", countDownInt];
        --countDownInt;
    }];
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.0];
    SKAction *updateLabelAndWait = [SKAction sequence:@[updateLabel, wait]];
    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:updateLabelAndWait count:secondsLeft] completion:^{
        gameTimerLabel.text = @"Time's Up";
    }];
}
```

thats all. thanks again to Ben-G for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: To stop NSTimer :
    [autoTimer invalidate];
    autoTimer = nil;

Comment: If you use an `SKAction` instead of an `NSTimer`, the countdown timer would automatically pause/resume when you move to/from background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though it doesn't answer your question exactly, I would refer to the accepted answer of this question: [SpriteKit - Creating a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978209/spritekit-creating-a-timer).

In general you want to avoid using `NSTimer` when working with a game engine. Your timed actions will not be integrated with the game loop and your timers won't be stopped automatically when the game is paused.

Instead integrate with the `update` method or use an `SKAction`.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach. I'll try the skaction when I get home tonight and let you know.

Comment: ok i figured it out. good approach. i am updating my question with the code i am using now so others can have a working code. thanks for the answer.