# Pausing scene when game was interrupted

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Another question: I call the function which generates sprites per time. But when I interrupt the game, for example picking up the call or double-click home button and go to task-manager, my scene doesn't stop and continue calling this function (oh, in this function i recall it per random time, cause in didMoveToView it calls once). So how stop the scene when game was interrupted?
Thank you!

```
func spawnRocks(){

 if gameOver == 0{

    score++
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"

    let rockPosition = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.height/1.5)
    var rockAmount = CGFloat(rockPosition) - self.frame.size.height/4

    var rockTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: randomRock())
    rock = SKSpriteNode(texture: rockTexture)

    rock.setScale(randomRockScale())

    rock.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + self.frame.size.width, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + rockAmount)

    var moveRock = SKAction.moveByX(-self.frame.size.width*2, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(randomRockMove()))
    var removeRock = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    var moveRemoveRock = SKAction.sequence([moveRock, removeRock])
    rock.runAction(moveRemoveRock)
    rockObject.addChild(rock)

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(randomRockSpeed()), target: self, selector: Selector("spawnRocks"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this idea:

First of all when your app will enter into background `applicationDidEnterBackground` will call from AppDelegate so you can set one bool there with NSUserDefaults which you can access anywhere is your project and set it this way:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "BackGround")

}
```

Now in your `GameViewController.swift` make if false when you load your game again like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "BackGround")
}
```

and now you can read that `NSUserDefaults` in your function and you can stop it if your bool is true this way:

```
func spawnRocks(){

    let backGround = NSUserDefaults().boolForKey("BackGround")
    if !backGround {

        if gameOver == 0{

            score++
            scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"

            let rockPosition = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.height/1.5)
            var rockAmount = CGFloat(rockPosition) - self.frame.size.height/4

            var rockTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: randomRock())
            rock = SKSpriteNode(texture: rockTexture)

            rock.setScale(randomRockScale())

            rock.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + self.frame.size.width, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + rockAmount)

            var moveRock = SKAction.moveByX(-self.frame.size.width*2, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(randomRockMove()))
            var removeRock = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            var moveRemoveRock = SKAction.sequence([moveRock, removeRock])
            rock.runAction(moveRemoveRock)
            rockObject.addChild(rock)

            NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(randomRockSpeed()), target: self, selector: Selector("spawnRocks"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
    }
}
```

After that when user open app again from background you can set that bool false again from AppDelegate this way:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "BackGround")
}
```

Hope It will help you.

Comment: what is the issue then?

Comment: I think i should make an action and function that gonna be returning a node, and an action that will be repeating forever in didMoveToView

Comment: so i think the problem is in NSTimer

Comment: you can invalidate that timer with this bool put that in else condition

Comment: You mean check entering background?

Comment: @DmitriyVinnichuk You should avoid using NSTimer in SpriteKit. I mentioned this in my answer, but you can read more here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/23978209/3402095 Better way would be to use SKAction or update: method and its currentTime parameter.

Comment: Yes I am agreed with @Whirlwind. you should follow his suggestion.

Comment: yes yes, @Whirlwind, thank you, that what i was thinking about. and... FOR KHAZ'MODAN

Answer (score 0):

SpriteKit in iOS 8 should automatically pause/resume your game (when app is moving to background or when exiting from background mode). In iOS 7 you should handle this manually. Search StackOverflow, there are some answers about this topic. Search about methods like aplicationWillResignActive, applicationDidEnterBackground, applicationDidBecomeActive) Also check the [paused](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKView/paused) property of a view.

But, I guess that problem is with NSTimer which don't respect scene's or view's paused state. Try using action sequence instead with delay and block of code to spawn rocks. That should help.

Answer (score 0):

Better use action on repeating and avoid NSTimer in SpriteKit