# Can't reference Xcode GameScene.sks with swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am a beginer and starting my first swift game. It seems like the GameScene.sks interface would be extrememly easy to position my labels and nodes for each level, but I am having trouble figuring out how to reference the nodes with swift. 
For example I dragged over a label to act as a timer, but I dont know how to update the label text with code. 
I was thinking something like:

```
func timerDidFire(){
    countDown--
    SKLabelNode.name("countDownTimerLabel").text = countDown
}
```

Comment: Are you using an `NSTimer`? If you are, take a look at: [Spritekit - Creating a timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978209/spritekit-creating-a-timer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `childNodeWithName` method on [`SKNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/childNodeWithName:). For example:

```
func timerDidFire() {
    let label = childNodeWithName("countDownTimerLabel") as! SKLabelNode
    label.text = --countDown

    // I believe this is an appropriate case for force unwrapping since you're going to 
    // want to know if your scene doesn't contain your label node. 
}
```

Since you're going to be accessing the `SKLabelNode` often, and it takes time to search through the node tree (not very much but something to bear in mind), it may be a good idea to keep a reference to the label. For example, in your `SKScene` subclass:

```
lazy var labelNode: SKLabelNode = self.childNodeWithName("countDownTimerLabel") as! SKLabelNode
```

On a related note, if you're looking for multiple nodes there's the 
[`enumerateChildNodesWithName(_:usingBlock:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:), also on `SKNode`.

Finally, for more information have a look at [Apple's WWDC 2014 talk: Best Practices for Building SpriteKit Games](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#608) where they cover both the methods I mentioned.