# Unable to use moveToY SKAction

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In my code I am essentially trying to make a galaga. Although when I try to get the enemies to fall using `moveToY` they stay stationary. I tried switching where the enemy should move to but that did nothing. I am trying not use a physics body.

```
import SpriteKit

var guy = SKSpriteNode()
var bullet = SKSpriteNode()
var badGuy = SKSpriteNode()


class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()

    guy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "guy")
    guy.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/6)
    guy.setScale(0.5)
    addChild(guy)

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnBullets"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    var enemyTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnBadGuys"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func spawnBullets(){

    bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
    bullet.setScale(0.5)
    bullet.zPosition = -5
    bullet.position = CGPointMake(guy.position.x, guy.position.y)
    let action = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + 30, duration: 1)
    bullet.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
    self.addChild(bullet)
}

func spawnBadGuys(){

    badGuy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "badGuy")
    var minValue = self.size.width/8
    var maxValue = self.size.width - 20
    var spawnPoint = UInt32(maxValue - minValue)
    badGuy.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(spawnPoint)), y: self.size.height)
    let action = SKAction.moveToY(-35, duration: 3.0)
    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
    self.addChild(badGuy)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        guy.position.x = location.x
        if guy.position.y != self.frame.height/6{
            guy.position.y = self.frame.size.height/6

               }
    }

}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        guy.position.x = location.x
        if guy.position.y != self.frame.height/6{
            guy.position.y = self.frame.size.height/6
        }


    }

}


}
```

Comment: Note that you don't really need a property called badGuy. It keeps a reference only to last spawned enemy...You should create a local variable in spawnBadGuys() method (`let badGuy = ...`), unless you really need the reference to the last spawned enemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run action on the badGuy (instead of on the scene):

```
func spawnBadGuys(){         
        //...
        badGuy.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))     
}
```

Hints:

- You should remove off-screen nodes because you can easily run into performance issues. Even bullets are not visible when go off-screen, they are still in the node graph and taking up memory.
- Using `SKAction` for time related actions in SpriteKit is always a better idea than using `NSTimer`. `NSTimer` doesn't respect node's, view's or scene's paused state. So, if user receives a phone call (and there is no custom pause feature implemented for `NSTimer`) instead of having the spawning paused, it will continue. So when app returns from background to foreground, the user will have a full screen of enemies. And that is not what you want. Pausing/unpausing is done automatically if you use `SKAction` or update: method and its `currentTime` parameter. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23978854/3402095)

Comment: thx a lot i had planned to add removing sprites i was just focused on making the sprites fall. I am new to swift.