# How to properly manage groups of sprites onscreen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm building my first game in Swift and I wanted to know how to go about handling multiple on screen sprites at once. My game pushes sprites on to screen with `addChild` continuously, so there are many active at once. I realized that I didn't have a proper way of simultaneously affecting all of them- like if I wanted to affect a physics property of all enemy sprites at once. So far I created an empty array `var enemySprites = [enemyType1]()` at the begining of `GameScene` and have been `appending` the sprite instances to it instead of using `addChild` to draw them directly to the scene. However, I'm not able to simply loop through and draw them to screen with:

```
    for enemy in enemySprites{
        addChild(enemy)
    }
```

this bit of code is in the `override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)` function, so maybe I'm just misplacing it? Any help on how to go about this would be great!

Comment: It is simple. Give them a name and enumerate them by that name. Or keep them in array and loop through that array. Looping through array in order to add sprites to the scene should work, but you probably don't want to do that in update: method (which is executed 60 times per sec). Also you may check if sprite has a parent before you add them.

Comment: @whirlwind Where should I do that then? The array is continually being updated as new enemies should be pushed and old(killed) ones should be removed, so I'm not sure when or when I should be looping through the array to either `addChild(newEnemy)` to the scene or to also effect all of them at once (like a physics property).

Comment: It depends of what you are trying to achieve. I don't really get what you want, but  it seems that @AlessandroOrnano gave you the right directions. For example, if you want to affect all nodes when a certain contact occur, then you should enumerate nodes in didBeginContact or similar methods. Or if you want to do the same thing, but when user touches the screen, you will do that in touchesBegan. Or if you want to do this after certain animation is done, then do it in completion handler of that animation. It is really up to you.

Comment: You certainly don't want to do this in update(), as this function is called automatically 60 times per second (if possible), so you'd try to add sprites you've already added, Plus you don't need to keep your sprites in an array as they are already in an array within the scene's node tree. Just give each type of sprite a name (via its .name property) and enumerate over all off them with enumerateChildNodeWithName in update() to move them.

Comment: @steveIves I'm not sure how I would implement what I want using this. If my character runs out of lives, then all onscreen & future enemies with name "type1" should have their physics bodies affected in some way- like velocity=(0,0). I'm not sure what the block parameter is to achieve this? could you elaborate? I looked on the docs and am still confused.

Comment: It is likely that you are over thinking this, just put refs to the different textures into an array and update the array when you add or delete one (not in the update method). You can then easily for loop over all the N textures in a specific array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam,

Here's some sample code to update enemies when your lives reach 0:

First, we set a property observer on the `lives` property so we can call a function when you lose all lives:

```
var lives = 3 {
    didSet {
        if lives == 0 {
        updateEnemies()
    }
}
```

And then a function to enumerate over all the enemies and change each one's velocity to (0, 0):

```
func update enemies() {
        enumerateChildNodesWithName("type1") {
            node, stop in
            let enemy = node as! SKSpriteNode
            enemy.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I actually stumbled upon something very similar to this. Is there anyway that you could explain the `!` at the end of `as!`? I understand that you're essentially type casting the variable enemy of type `node` into a type of `SKSpriteNode`, but I don't get why you needed the optional part `!`. Also, if there are any resources that you'd recommend for optionals because I've done research and just can't seem to fully get it. (Also did you mean `lives` instead of `ships`?) Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: @Sam Sorry it's lives, not ships (took it from my code). Let me look into the other stuff, but there lots of explanation about optionals on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use `update` method, you could use a timer. From sources:

```
public class func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(ti: NSTimeInterval, target aTarget: AnyObject, selector aSelector: Selector, userInfo: AnyObject?, repeats yesOrNo: Bool) -> NSTimer
```

So if you follow Apple guide, it will be for example:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnAlien:"), userInfo: myParameter, repeats: true)

func spawnAlien(timer : NSTimer) {
      if let myUserInfo = timer.userInfo {
         print(myUserInfo) // a parameters passed to help you to the alien creation
      }
      timer.invalidate()
}
```

**BUT** according to `Whirlwind` I agree with him and with [LearnCocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23978854/1894067) work, **sprite-kit don't work well with timers** (as explained in the link by `LearnCocos2d`) and the better way, especially as you say you develop your first game, it's to use `SKAction`, a combination of actions to achieve the similar behavior obtained by `NSTimer`.

I've think about a function or an extension, let me know if it's work as expected:

```
extension SKAction {
   class func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(time:NSTimeInterval, selector: Selector, repeats:Bool)->SKAction {
      let call = SKAction.customActionWithDuration(0.0) { node, _ in
          node.performSelector(selector)
      }
      let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(time)
      let seq = SKAction.sequence([wait,call])
      let callSelector = repeats ? SKAction.repeatActionForever(seq) : seq
      return callSelector
   } 
}
```

**Usage**:

```
let spawn = SKAction.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(time, selector: #selector(GenericArea.spawnAlien), repeats: true)
self.runAction(spawn,withKey: "spawnAlien")
```

Comment: Does this help with modifying all enemys at once?

Comment: What do you mean for modifying all enemies at once? What's your purpose?

Comment: For example, I may have ten enemies on screen but then if I bump into one I lose the game. I want them to all still float around but they shouldn't be able to collide with me anymore and should move at a slower rate. To achieve this, any new enemy instances that I generate will be modified with an `if statement`. However, all enemies that were already on screen wont be effected. Had they always been in an array or something I should be able to effect all sprites. (This is just an example of what I mean).

Comment: Every time you create an alien, create also his physicsbody and his bitmasks, then handle collisions with didBeginContact

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano Is there any reason why you proposed NSTimer here, instead of SKActions / update: method ? Because NSTimer is not automatically paused when view, scene or a node is paused. So custom pause feature is required in many cases...

Comment: @Whirlwind  you can invalidate and reproposal a timer if you want to make a pause, and of course you must do a custom method to pause ( common thing). I think using update is dangerous to continuously spawn nodes, there are other ways, I've think to timer

Comment: Well, okay, it is true. But it is easier to use SKAction sequence to implement spawning, and do nothing when app goes to background or user receives phone call, or something like that, instead of doing what you said. Also take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23978854/3402095 The part "Moreover you do not know at which point in the game loop they are executed..." is interesting. Haven't tested that closely, but personally, I think SKActions and update: method are safer. You can implement ticker using update method safely as well. It is just ugly way IMO  :), but certainly safe.

Comment: With SKAction you must pass to runBlock, I dont like the behaviour of runblock with other skactions, but it could be another way to do

Comment: @Whirlwind At the end I've decide to follow LearnCocos2D and your advice, maybe can make an easiest life to who develop on sprite-kit from recently. Thank you for your intervention.