# iOS SpriteKit - countdown before game starts?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Just getting into SpriteKit on iOS using Swift. I have a 'Breakout' game from a tutorial and I want to implement a countdown before every ball launches, by putting an SKLabel in the middle of the screen which counts down from 5 to 1 before removing itself and the game starting. Whilst the countdown is going on, you can see the full games screen with the wall, stationary ball etc.

I can't work out where in the game loop to do this. If I do the countdown in didMoveToView (where I create the wall and initialise the ball and paddle), I never see it, but I see my debugging messages in the log. I guess that didMoveToView is called before the SKScene is presented.

I tried to use a flag to call the countdown function the first time 'Update' is called, but again I saw the countdown executed before anything appeared on screen - i think 'update' is called initially before the scene is rendered.

I could implement a 'Tap screen to start' screen in a another SKScene, but I really wanted a countdown on the screen with the wall and the (stationary) ball ready to go. I could create this countdown scene using a background image of the game screen, but this seems awkward.

Any suggestions gratefully received,

Steve

Comment: It's never a good sign when you Google for a solution and the top hit is your own question on SO...

Comment: update  is called exactly once per frame

Comment: @SteveIves Check out my solution with NSTimers below and let me know if anything doesn't work.

Comment: Ok - bit of a learning experience here. It suddenly hit me why my SKSpritelabel countdown worked in didMoveToView but not in Update - updating an SKLabel in a loop in Update won't work because the label isn't re-rendered between iterations, unlike a UILabel in a UIView. Obvious once you think about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Added these functions and a call to `countdown(5)` at the end of `didMoveToView`

```
func countdown(count: Int) {
    countdownLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Center
    countdownLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = .Baseline
    countdownLabel.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height*(1/3))
    countdownLabel.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    countdownLabel.fontSize = size.height / 30
    countdownLabel.zPosition = 100
    countdownLabel.text = "Launching ball in \(count)..."

addChild(countdownLabel)

let counterDecrement = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0),
    SKAction.runBlock(countdownAction)])

runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.repeatAction(counterDecrement, count: 5),
    SKAction.runBlock(endCountdown)]))

}

func countdownAction() {
    count--
    countdownLabel.text = "Launching ball in \(count)..."
}

func endCountdown() {
    countdownLabel.removeFromParent()
    ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(20, 20))
}
```

So I create and set up the text of the countdown and then create and run an SKAction that waits for 1 second before decrementing the countdown and updating the label. It repeats this 5 times and then removes the countdown label before finally giving the ball an impulse to start it moving and so the game proper can start.

Seems to work ok...

Comment: Being new to SpriteKit, I'd be interested to hear if this is a good or bad way to do it...

Answer (score 2):

This is where `NSTimer`s really come in handy. An NSTimer basically activates a function every so often (you specify how often).

**Update:** Sometimes it's better not to use an NSTimer; see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24950982/5700898

Here's a code sample, using NSTimer:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var countdownTime = 5
var countdownTimer = NSTimer()
// above, setting your timer and countdown time as global variables so they can be accessed in multiple functions.

func PlayerPressesStart() {
countdownTime = 5
countdownTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "Countdown", userInfo: nil, repeats: true) // calls the function "Countdown" every second.
}

func Countdown() { // this is the function called by the timer every second, which causes your "countdownTime" to go down by 1. When it reaches 0, it starts the game.
countdownTime--
if countdownTime > 0 {
countdownTimer.invalidate()
placewhereyoudisplaycountdown.text = String(countdownTime)
}
if countdownTime == 0 {
// call the function where game action begins here, or call the function that makes the game begin here.
}
} // closing bracket for the View Controller, don't include this if you're copying and pasting to your already existing View Controller.
```

Comment: Thanks John. I'll give this a try as well as seeing if I can get an SKAction to decrement my countdown SKLabel from 5 to 1 over 5 seconds before firing the ball off (probably by giving it an impulse when the action has completed).

Comment: Thanks for the code sample John, but following the advice  not to use NSTimer in SpriteKit, I went straight for the SKAction technique.